# How do you choose whether or not to use a system call vs a library function as a systems programmer?

Tags: c, system

When you develop a system program such as ls, who, more, etc. there are usually multiple ways to do system related things, such as opening a file - open vs fopen, for example. How, as a developer, do you decide whether or not to use a library function vs a system call? I get it that kernel programmers tend to use system calls as higher level functions aren't available to the kernel, and that application developers can freely choose higher level calls, but what about systems programmers sitting in the middle? Is there a clear set of criteria?

Comment: Don't use system calls directly. Unless you are developing a standard library (e.i. libc) or are implementing something very specific that uses a system call that is not implemented by a standard library (e.g. kexec).

Comment: You want to make your program as portable as possible. So you want to rely on abstractions as much as possible. If a certain functionality is wrapped into a library function, you better use it and not to care whether it is implemented using a system call or not.

Comment: @Cheatah I edited a bit on the kernel dev's use of system calls